# How can I pass a FileStream to a blackbox library that opens a file via file path?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a blackbox library that takes a filepath, opens the file, and uploads it to a third party hosted service. Something like:

```
Public UploadResult UploadFileTo3rdPartySystem(string FilePath){...
```

I'm receiving these files as a FileStream. The simple solution would be to save the file to disk and pass the path to UploadFileTo3rdPartySystem(). My issue is that these files contain personal, non-public information. As such I'd like to avoid keeping the file on the filesystem if at all possible.

What I'd like to achieve is some sort of "virtual file system", in which I can:

1. Keep the contents of the incoming FileStream in memory.
2. Create a virtual file that references the FileStream in memory.
3. Pass the path of the virtual file to UploadFileTo3rdPartySystem(), which will pull the contents of the incoming FileStream from memory.

Is this even possible?

EDIT: In summary, I have a FileStream. I have a method in a library (that I cannot modify) that takes a file path as an parameter. I need to pass the contents of the incoming FileStream to this method that only takes file path without saving the contents of the FileStream to disk.

Comment: I'm afraid, you cannot do this (with observable lines of code). It will be simpler to write your own library instead of your black box. Or you can save file to disk and pass this filename to library, then remove file from disk

Comment: Why don't you try using IsolatedStorage? This of course doesn't keep everything in RAM, but you could use it with SecureString:  See  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(v=vs.110).aspx  and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx

Comment: @user89861 Will that work? The library only receives the filepath, which it uses to open a FileStream. I was under the impression that I can't read files out of IsolatedStorage without using IsolatedStorageFileStream, which is a problem since I can't modify the library that is opening the file.

Am I mistaken?

Comment: Couldn't you use IsolatedStorageFileStream yourself to read the file in, then read it in to FileStream in your app and pass it to your 3 party system?

Comment: Try a MemoryStream which is part of the IO library.

Comment: @user89861 Unfortunately not. The only way to get this file to our third party is through a method that takes a filepath (which then gets opened via FileStream). There's no way to pass a FileStream directly to that method. 

The obvious way is to save the file to a disk, then pass the filepath to UploadFileTo3rdPartySystem(), but considering the contents of these files I'd like to avoid this if at all possible.

Comment: @jdweng How can I reference the contents of a MemoryStream as a file path?

Comment: Well, how about using a named pipe? That also has a filename, which may be transparently supported by the 3rd party library. And you can feed your end of that pipe from your stream. While the OS may still buffer some data to disk, the attack surface should me much smaller than a real file.

Comment: @Zastai That's a great idea! A little more complex than I would have liked, but it's a feasible solution! Thank you!

Comment: A stream is a pipe.  Lets not get into terminology issues.  See webpage for MemoryStream : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx.  A pipe is usually used to go between two different processes.  A MemoryStream is used within a single process.

Comment: _"I'm receiving these files as a FileStream" -- I don't understand your question. If you actually have a `FileStream` object in hand, why can't you just pass that object's `Name` property value to the library?